# Is there a grep equivalent in TACL on HP-Nonstop?

Tags: hp-nonstop, tandem

As it says in the title; if yes, I would, of course, need a bash-like pipe in order to use it comfortably.

Comment: There is 'locate' but I am not sure if its available on all systems

Answer (score 1):

If your system has `OSS`, you can use `gtacl`. `gtacl` allows you to start a `TACL` aka a Guardian program directly from `OSS`, which has `grep` natively.

To switch sessions from Guardian `TACL` to `OSS`, first type `osh` and then you can simply run your `TACL` commands via `gtacl -c STATUS *, DETAIL` (this is a user status example).

You can run all of your `TACL` commands this way while in `OSS`, just as you would have to run all of your `osh` commands for `OSS` as `osh -c "ps -e~|egrep -e 'sshd~|prngd'"` (example osh process checks ssh) when in the `TACL` session.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to know how to search string from file by tacl

reading file to varaible

```
FILETOVAR file-name variable-level

exmple: FILETOVAR $AAA.BBB.CCC var
    $AAA.BBB.CCC: filename
    var: variable name
```

find string in var

```
VFIND var string

   var：variable name
   string : target string
```

Answer (score 0):

Grep does many things.

If you are looking in a specific file for a string, the command:
EDIT  R;LB/String/All;E

will look in single Editable files (type 101).

If you are looking in multiple files in a $. directory, there isn't any HPNonStop utility to accomplish that.

You could surround the single file example above with TACL code to look at all editable files.  Something like:

**FooFind**

```
?TACL Macro
#Frame
#Push StringToFind FileName StopLoop Vol SubVol

#Set StopLoop 0
#Set StringToFind %1%
#SetMany Vol SubVol, [#Fileinfo/volume,subvol/[#Defaults/Current/ ].a]

[#If [#Empty [StringToFind]]
|then|
  #Output Usage: Please supply the string to find
  #Output EG: Foofind foo
|else|
  #Set Filename [#Defaults/Current/].a
  [#Loop
  |do|
    #Set FileName [#NextFileName [FileName]]
    [#If [#Match [Vol] [#fileinfo/Volume/[FileName]]]
     And [#Match [Subvol] [#fileinfo/Subvol/[FileName]]]
    |then|
      [#If [#Match 101 [#fileinfo/Code/[FileName]]]
      |then|
        Edit [FileName] r;lb/[StringToFind]/;Exit
      |else|
        #Output [FileName] is not an Edit file. Skipping...
      ] == end of if
    |else|
      #Set StopLoop -1
    ] == end of if
  |Until| [StopLoop]
  ] == end of loop
] == end of if
#UnFrame
```

**Execution:**

$DATA FOO 73> foofind

Usage: Please supply the string to find

EG: Foofind foo

$DATA FOO 74> foofind foo

TEXT EDITOR - T9601L01 - (20OCT14)

CURRENT FILE IS $DATA.FOO.FOO1

TEXT EDITOR - T9601L01 - (20OCT14)

CURRENT FILE IS $DATA.FOO.FOO2

```
1     there is a foo here
```

TEXT EDITOR - T9601L01 - (20OCT14)

CURRENT FILE IS $DATA.FOO.FOO3

```
1     And a foo foo here.
```

TEXT EDITOR - T9601L01 - (20OCT14)

CURRENT FILE IS $DATA.FOO.FOOFIND

```
   12       #Output EG: Foofind foo
```

$DATA.FOO.NOTEDIT is not an Edit file. Skipping...

$DATA FOO 75>

This is pretty rudimentary.  There is lots of room for enhancements. But it does accomplish the task of looking for the input string in all editable files in a volume/sub-volume directory.

However, if you are looking for a grep-like utility that will search non-edit files, your best bet is to do something through a programming language.